# Is it some way to create different usage rights for a same page WITH NO logging?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angular

I have no idea what solution could does something like this.

I need webpage with 2 squares which will print on some big screen. There are 2  users, every of them needs access of writing in own square only on this page.

```
<div class="square1"> 
   <input type="text" id="square1"> 
</div>
<div class="square2"> 
   <input type="text" id="square2">
</div>
```

So, for example if I am user1 than input in square1 only is enabled for me and others inputs are disabled.

There are no troubles to make it with a logging service but is there some solution to make this functionality by using different weblinks for every user?

So, if I am user1 than I have such weblink: `www.thisideaweb.link/special-page.html?special-weblink-for-user1` and I could  edit only square1 input on this page and if I am user2 than my link is: `www.thisideaweb.link/special-page.html?special-weblink-for-user2` and I could edit only square2 input?

Comment: You can show only the input necessary for that user and not deal with disabling different inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage `ActivatedRoute` to get the url and parameters. Once you get url and params you can perform your `activation` of square.

Inject ActivatedRoute

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Read the URL

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
        this.route.url //<-- it will give the url
        //Enable/Disable the Sqaure
    });
  }
```

Comment: Indeed! That's what I do need! Thank you for your support. Appreciate it!